# Training Style Transfer Neural Network Leads to NANs

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've been encountering NANs while trying to train the Neural Style Transfer model from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.07629.pdf. I've tried reducing learning rate and using different initialisations but it doesn't seem to work. I suspect it has something to do with my training loop using tape.Gradient.

Here is my Image Transform Network:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, BatchNormalization, Add, ReLU, Reshape, UpSampling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import initializers

# initializers
initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=0.01, seed=None)
betaInitializer = initializers.constant(0.)
gammaInitializer = initializers.constant(1.)

# Conditional Instance Normalisation layer
class ConditionalInstanceNorm(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, scope_bn, y1, y2, alpha):
    super(ConditionalInstanceNorm, self).__init__()
    self.scope_bn = scope_bn
    self.y1 = y1
    self.y2 = y2
    self.alpha = alpha
  
  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.beta = self.add_weight(name="beta"+self.scope_bn, shape=(self.y1.shape[-1], input_shape[-1]), initializer=betaInitializer, trainable=True)
    self.gamma = self.add_weight(name="gamma"+self.scope_bn, shape=(self.y1.shape[-1], input_shape[-1]), initializer=gammaInitializer, trainable=True)
  
  def call(self, inputs):
    mean, var = tf.nn.moments(x=inputs, axes=[1,2], keepdims=True)
    beta1 = tf.matmul(self.y1, self.beta)
    gamma1 = tf.matmul(self.y1, self.gamma)
    beta2 = tf.matmul(self.y2, self.beta)
    gamma2 = tf.matmul(self.y2, self.gamma)
    beta = self.alpha*beta1 + (1. - self.alpha)*beta2
    gamma = self.alpha*gamma1 + (1. - self.alpha)*gamma2
    x = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x=inputs, mean=mean, variance=var, offset=beta, scale=gamma, variance_epsilon=1e-10)
    return x

# Applies upsampling if stride = 0.5, includes mirror padding, conv layer and conditional instance Norm layer
def PadConvBatch(x, filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation='relu', scope_bn="", y1=None, y2=None, alpha=1):
  if isinstance(strides, float):
    x = UpSampling2D(size=2, interpolation='nearest')(x)
    strides=1
  padding = tf.cast((kernel_size-1)/2, tf.int32)
  x = tf.pad(x, [[0,0], [padding,padding], [padding,padding], [0,0]], "REFLECT")
  x = Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=strides, activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)(x)
  conditionalInstanceNorm = ConditionalInstanceNorm(scope_bn=scope_bn, y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha)
  x = conditionalInstanceNorm(x)
  return x

# Implementation of resnet block according to paper
def resblock(x, scope_bn1="", scope_bn2="", y1=None, y2=None, alpha=1):
  fx = PadConvBatch(x=x, filters=128, activation="linear", scope_bn=scope_bn1, y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha)
  fx = ReLU()(fx)
  fx = PadConvBatch(x=fx, filters=128, activation="linear", scope_bn=scope_bn2, y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha)
  out = Add()([x,fx])
  return out

# Overall network
def ImageTransformNetwork(shape=(256,256,3), y1=None, y2=None, alpha=1):
  inputs = Input(shape=shape) #1
  x = PadConvBatch(x=inputs, kernel_size=9, scope_bn="1", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha) #3
  x = PadConvBatch(x=x, filters=64, strides=2, scope_bn="2", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha) #5
  x = PadConvBatch(x=x, filters=128, strides=2, scope_bn="3", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha) #7
  x = resblock(x=x, scope_bn1="4", scope_bn2="5", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha) #13
  x = resblock(x=x, scope_bn1="6", scope_bn2="7", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha) #19
  x = resblock(x=x, scope_bn1="8", scope_bn2="9", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha) #25
  x = resblock(x=x, scope_bn1="10", scope_bn2="11", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha) #31
  x = resblock(x=x, scope_bn1="12", scope_bn2="13", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha) #37
  x = PadConvBatch(x=x, filters=64, strides=0.5, scope_bn="14", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha) #39
  x = PadConvBatch(x=x, filters=32, strides=0.5, scope_bn="15", y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha) #41
  x = tf.pad(x, [[0,0], [4,4], [4,4], [0,0]], "REFLECT")
  x = Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=9, strides=1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=initializer)(x) #42
  x = x*255
  model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
  return model
```

Here is my loss network:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

#config
os.environ['TFHUB_MODEL_LOAD_FORMAT'] = 'COMPRESSED'

#Specify layers for content and style representation
content_layers = ['block4_conv2']
style_layers = ['block1_conv1', 'block2_conv1', 'block3_conv1', 'block4_conv1', 'block5_conv1']

# Find number of layers
num_content_layers = len(content_layers)
num_style_layers = len(style_layers)

# Grab vgg19 network without dense layers
def vgg_layers(layer_names):
  vgg = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

  outputs = [vgg.get_layer(name).output for name in layer_names]

  model = tf.keras.Model([vgg.input], outputs)
  return model

# Calculate normalised gram matrix
def gram_matrix(input_tensor):
  result = tf.linalg.einsum('bijc,bijd->bcd', input_tensor, input_tensor)
  input_shape = tf.shape(input_tensor)
  num_locations = tf.cast(input_shape[1]*input_shape[2], tf.float32)
  return result/(num_locations)

# Setting up loss network model class + forward method
class LossNetwork(tf.keras.models.Model):
  def __init__(self, style_layers, content_layers):
    super(LossNetwork, self).__init__()
    self.vgg = vgg_layers(style_layers+content_layers)
    self.style_layers = style_layers
    self.content_layers = content_layers
    self.num_style_layers = len(style_layers)
    self.vgg.trainable = False
  
  def call(self, inputs):
    inputs = inputs*255.0
    preprocessed_input = tf.keras.applications.vgg19.preprocess_input(inputs)
    outputs = self.vgg(preprocessed_input)
    style_outputs, content_outputs = (outputs[:self.num_style_layers], outputs[self.num_style_layers:])

    style_outputs = [gram_matrix(style_output) for style_output in style_outputs]
    content_dict = {content_name: value for content_name, value in zip(self.content_layers, content_outputs)}
    style_dict = {style_name: value for style_name, value in zip(self.style_layers, style_outputs)}
    return {'content': content_dict, 'style': style_dict}

# returns network
def loadLossNetwork():
  return LossNetwork(style_layers, content_layers)
```

As for training, I'm currently testing it out by only using batch size of 1 and using only 1 image. Here is my training code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time
import functools

import ImageTransformNetwork
import ImagePreProcessing
import LossNetwork

import PIL.Image

"""Utility and Loss Functions START"""
#Converts a tensor into an image
def tensor_to_image(tensor):
  #Multiplies every element in tensor by 255
  tensor = tensor*255

  #Converts tensor into a numpy array
  tensor = np.array(tensor, dtype=np.uint8)

  if np.ndim(tensor)>3:
    #Ensures only 1 image is being sent
    assert tensor.shape[0] == 1

    #Takes out the first element so you just get a 3 dim np array
    tensor = tensor[0]
  
  #Converts numpy array into PIL image
  return PIL.Image.fromarray(tensor)

# Calculates style and content loss in loss network
def style_content_loss(outputs):
  style_outputs = outputs['style']
  content_outputs = outputs['content']

  style_loss_total = tf.constant(0.0, tf.float32)
  for name in style_outputs.keys():
    style_loss_total += tf.reduce_sum((style_outputs[name]-style_targets[name])**2)*style_weight/batch_size
  
  content_loss_total = 0
  for name in content_outputs.keys():
    content_loss_total += ((content_outputs[name] - content_targets[name])**2)
    content_loss_total *= content_weight/(content_outputs[name].shape[1]*content_outputs[name].shape[2])

  loss = style_loss_total + content_loss_total

  return loss

"""Utility and Loss Functions END"""


"""Setup START"""
#Loads images
content_image, style_image = ImagePreProcessing.loadImage()
content_image = tf.image.resize(content_image, [256,256])
content_image = tf.reshape(content_image, [1,256,256,3])

y1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,10]))
y2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,10]))
alpha = tf.constant([1.])

#Calls instance of image transform network and loss network
imageTransformNetwork = ImageTransformNetwork.ImageTransformNetwork(y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha)
lossNetwork = LossNetwork.loadLossNetwork()

# Obtain features of each layer of loss network model
style_targets = lossNetwork(style_image)['style']
content_targets = lossNetwork(content_image)['content']

#Sets optimiser, LBFGS is better
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-1)

"""Setup END"""


"""Train START"""

#Training step
style_weight = 1e-2
content_weight = 1e4
total_variation_weight = 30

@tf.function()
def train_step(image):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    stylised = imageTransformNetwork(image, training=True)
    outputs = lossNetwork(stylised)

    loss = style_content_loss(outputs)
  
  grad = tape.gradient(loss, imageTransformNetwork.trainable_variables)
  opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, imageTransformNetwork.trainable_variables))

#Optimisation loop
epochs = 1
steps_per_epoch = 5
batch_size = 1

start = time.time()
step = 0
for n in range(epochs):
  for m in range(steps_per_epoch):
    step += 1
    train_step(content_image)
    print(".", end='', flush=True)
  print('Train step: {}'.format(step))
end=time.time()
print('Total time: {:.1f}'.format(end-start))

print(imageTransformNetwork.layers[15].weights)
stylised_tensor = imageTransformNetwork(content_image)
print(stylised_tensor)
stylised_image = tensor_to_image(stylised_tensor)
stylised_image.show()

"""Train END"""
```

Here are the weights of my Action Transform Network after 5 epochs:

> [<tf.Variable 'conv2d_4/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 128, 128)
> dtype=float32, numpy= array([[[[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
> ...,
> [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
> [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],
>
> ```
>     [[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      ...,
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],
>
>     [[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      ...,
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]]],
>
>
>    [[[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      ...,
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],
>
>     [[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      ...,
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],
>
>     [[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      ...,
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]]],
>
>
>    [[[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      ...,
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],
>
>     [[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      ...,
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],
>
>     [[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      ...,
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
>      [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]]]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_4/bias:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32, numpy=
> ```
>
> array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
> dtype=float32)>]

Is there anything wrong with my code that could lead to this?

Comment: Usually this means that *somewhere* a single `nan` value pops up, which then keeps on being iterated through all of the code, changing every single numerical value it interacts with to `nan`. In other words: step through your code line-by-line and find out where the first `nan` shows up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I went through the first training step and there was nothing wrong with every layer. Then after the second step the bias of the final convolutional layer went from 0. to NAN

Comment: I also checked my loss and it was massive, 23 orders of magnitude on the first iteration, then it went to -NaNs

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, I was re-programming my training code to make it more clear and accidentally fixed it. The issue was that my y1 tensor was all zeroes, hence the beta and gamma values in the Instance Normalisation Layers were all 0, thus in some way leading to the propagation of NaN values. I also realised I should not add `x = x*255` at the end of my Image Transform Network and another `input = 255*input` at the beginning of the vgg network which inflated my values.

```
import tensorflow as tf

import ImageProcessing
import LossNetwork
import ImageTransformNetwork

def train(epochs=1, ylabel=0, style_weight=1e-2, content_weight=1e4, batch_size=16):
  train_dataset, style_image = ImageProcessing.loadDataset("Picture/", "chosen_pictures/candle_dancer,nolde.jpeg", batch_size)

  y1 = [[0 for i in range(10)]]
  y1[0][ylabel] = 1
  y1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(y1, dtype=tf.float32)
  y2 = tf.zeros([1,10])
  alpha = tf.constant([1.])

  imageTransformNetwork = ImageTransformNetwork.ImageTransformNetwork(y1=y1, y2=y2, alpha=alpha)
  lossNetwork = LossNetwork.loadLossNetwork()

  style_targets = lossNetwork(style_image)["style"]

  opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-1)

  step = 0
  for epochs in range(epochs):
    for i, batch in enumerate(train_dataset):
      step += 1
      batch = rescaling(batch)
      with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        stylised = imageTransformNetwork(batch, training=True)
        outputs = lossNetwork(stylised)
        content_targets = lossNetwork(batch)["content"]

        loss = LossNetwork.style_content_loss(outputs, style_targets, content_targets, style_weight, content_weight, batch_size)

      grad = tape.gradient(loss, imageTransformNetwork.trainable_weights)
      opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, imageTransformNetwork.trainable_weights))

      tf.print(loss)

      if step%500 == 0:
        model.save("savedModels/model"+step//500)

rescaling = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(None, None, 3), dtype=tf.float32)

train()
```

The resulting weights no longer contains any NaNs:

> [<tf.Variable 'conv2d_4/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 128, 128)
> dtype=float32, numpy= array([[[[-9.22914653e-04, -3.25754564e-03,
> 2.19115964e-03, ...,
> -1.54448478e-02,  6.85744826e-03, -3.45157599e-03],
> [ 1.11031579e-02, -1.67974327e-02, -9.00101440e-04, ...,
> 2.80345492e-02,  1.03713870e-02,  7.72784650e-03],
> [ 6.38803188e-03,  1.52107864e-03,  3.26261576e-03, ...,
> -1.68494694e-03, -1.20439203e-02, -3.61325294e-02],
> ...,
> [ 1.20753944e-02,  3.71512910e-03,  2.29522269e-02, ...,
> 5.69997064e-04, -9.27594118e-03, -2.40900833e-02],
> [-4.25596721e-03,  3.20109446e-03, -1.33239599e-02, ...,
> -9.32860561e-03,  1.42052788e-02, -1.05757872e-03],
> [ 1.85675547e-02,  1.12123555e-02, -7.40887132e-03, ...,
> -5.26969973e-03, -4.57865652e-03,  2.60398141e-03]],
>
> ```
>     [[ 6.01717457e-03, -1.17905010e-02, -1.26012340e-02, ...,
>       -2.16883258e-03,  1.40141053e-02, -4.93765983e-04],
>      [-1.18666200e-03, -6.67788927e-03,  5.93844941e-03, ...,
>        1.05758598e-02, -1.33344317e-02,  4.41704318e-03],
>      [ 4.38539824e-03, -9.45210271e-03, -1.96239129e-02, ...,
>        1.58801023e-02,  1.40289860e-02, -9.41994600e-03],
>      ...,
>      [ 1.37740280e-05,  6.21070713e-03,  1.13504520e-03, ...,
>       -7.07426807e-03,  1.91432852e-02, -1.09282834e-02],
>      [ 2.73628104e-02, -1.65116577e-03, -1.41831292e-02, ...,
>       -1.61790382e-03, -7.22122053e-03, -1.38549581e-02],
>      [ 3.37673048e-03,  1.00006070e-02,  2.99341255e-03, ...,
>        8.13197810e-03, -1.22140273e-02, -2.28559617e-02]],
>
>     [[-4.94419318e-03, -1.06641259e-02, -1.19099990e-02, ...,
>        7.04542780e-03,  1.10173412e-02, -1.00985430e-02],
>      [-1.07495757e-02, -1.03038019e-02,  2.26744954e-02, ...,
>        2.91943387e-03, -2.27406379e-02, -1.16430689e-02],
>      [ 8.73126276e-03,  1.89025106e-03,  8.01201630e-03, ...,
>        5.62170707e-03,  6.12628879e-03, -2.53114733e-04],
>      ...,
>      [-9.01912060e-03,  1.86426658e-02,  7.42244720e-03, ...,
>       -7.43635232e-03,  1.84447784e-02,  5.29437512e-03],
>      [-2.77710403e-03, -1.11136436e-02,  4.61787265e-03, ...,
>        3.43568996e-03,  1.10518862e-03,  9.76805110e-03],
>      [ 1.84791256e-02,  1.40596041e-02,  2.54741148e-03, ...,
>       -3.77570093e-03,  6.19729050e-03,  2.31865281e-03]]],
>
>
>    [[[ 2.15795785e-02, -1.19263222e-02, -2.69088056e-03, ...,
>        1.32677099e-03,  8.45701247e-03, -1.88063979e-02],
>      [-9.04210471e-03, -5.87769412e-03, -5.84315648e-03, ...,
>        8.99547432e-03,  7.23270513e-03,  4.29085980e-04],
>      [ 6.83306810e-03,  1.70376035e-03,  1.41868247e-02, ...,
>       -2.99190381e-03,  1.33085134e-03, -1.67587642e-02],
>      ...,
>      [-1.36112515e-02,  5.13256202e-03,  5.86730288e-03, ...,
>        4.40224679e-03,  1.41993053e-02, -2.21067611e-02],
>      [ 6.86844671e-03, -3.06997774e-03, -1.56005612e-02, ...,
>        2.00642040e-03,  1.37336999e-02, -7.43707130e-03],
>      [-3.60132020e-04,  1.27417007e-02, -6.24217000e-03, ...,
>        8.11805599e-04, -6.68468559e-03,  1.66701805e-02]],
>
>     [[ 6.16356591e-03, -1.51706664e-02, -4.45271842e-03, ...,
>       -1.61965843e-03, -3.41256475e-03,  4.15274641e-03],
>      [ 7.08530797e-03,  3.43623164e-04,  3.02305375e-03, ...,
>       -1.34551339e-02, -7.74222892e-03, -9.40223970e-03],
>      [-3.96022515e-04, -1.76352914e-02,  4.82104952e-03, ...,
>        1.61363333e-02,  1.36647765e-02, -4.76737216e-04],
>      ...,
>      [ 3.33301607e-03, -4.36515687e-03, -1.00332387e-02, ...,
>       -7.81015400e-03, -9.20389965e-03, -1.65066053e-03],
>      [-4.91148187e-03, -1.87809812e-03, -5.74924750e-03, ...,
>        5.51467016e-03, -4.86751553e-03,  4.92513832e-03],
>      [ 2.10825708e-02,  6.21355977e-03, -3.15705035e-03, ...,
>        1.32449274e-03,  1.09589389e-02, -1.67893188e-03]],
>
>     [[ 7.25688133e-03, -8.45121965e-03, -8.33619572e-03, ...,
>        4.51847119e-03, -3.63183790e-03,  9.71599482e-03],
>      [-1.14116399e-03, -9.45648877e-04,  8.83929897e-03, ...,
>       -7.76065839e-03, -1.52589316e-02, -8.26635305e-03],
>      [-3.16444691e-03,  3.19679384e-03,  3.55893001e-03, ...,
>        7.63914781e-03, -3.52958916e-03, -1.72572676e-03],
>      ...,
>      [ 4.08169115e-03, -1.09134587e-02, -6.46053767e-03, ...,
>       -2.58600842e-02,  9.29399393e-03,  1.65797323e-02],
>      [ 1.06143337e-02, -1.58559270e-02, -1.03117265e-02, ...,
>       -1.52223487e-03, -6.32383861e-03, -3.65341373e-04],
>      [-4.81503829e-03, -4.38905088e-03, -4.73908149e-03, ...,
>       -5.55378292e-03,  2.71180947e-03, -5.92879718e-03]]],
>
>
>    [[[ 9.67705343e-03,  3.40853585e-03,  2.47258402e-04, ...,
>        1.45784477e-02, -1.67573560e-02, -2.56466400e-02],
>      [ 3.59606324e-03,  1.20630264e-02, -1.37810390e-02, ...,
>       -1.66904740e-03, -4.24776971e-03, -9.79586504e-03],
>      [ 4.21262113e-03, -9.41874983e-04,  6.73639216e-03, ...,
>        2.38019545e-02,  4.90003964e-03, -4.52585239e-03],
>      ...,
>      [ 4.01812606e-04,  8.53525288e-03, -1.20494002e-02, ...,
>        1.56634264e-02,  1.45185292e-02,  1.58445258e-02],
>      [ 1.92584179e-04, -4.28026915e-03,  8.10027216e-03, ...,
>        1.14922663e-02,  8.66387971e-03,  1.64663978e-03],
>      [ 1.83315924e-03,  1.86281260e-02,  5.20413416e-03, ...,
>        8.63858406e-03, -2.18354282e-04, -1.01757115e-02]],
>
>     [[ 2.81637791e-03, -4.76985564e-03, -1.39078144e-02, ...,
>       -1.58296956e-04,  1.62388422e-02,  2.44920887e-03],
>      [-2.65886029e-03, -1.00718942e-02, -9.38246213e-03, ...,
>       -7.73472525e-03, -7.73774413e-03,  1.22246624e-03],
>      [-9.11037438e-03, -2.70083174e-03, -1.20385522e-02, ...,
>       -1.91840120e-02,  8.58602673e-03,  4.00405657e-03],
>      ...,
>      [ 1.86355747e-02,  3.25039215e-03,  1.14641823e-02, ...,
>        2.52336729e-02,  7.14283716e-03, -1.11020561e-02],
>      [ 3.38363531e-03, -2.28321627e-02, -5.52309211e-03, ...,
>        9.30515677e-03, -7.97424931e-04,  7.66106136e-03],
>      [ 2.67876014e-02, -9.12602246e-03, -3.73603543e-04, ...,
>       -4.90523782e-03,  4.98087937e-03, -6.29857299e-04]],
>
>     [[ 2.37794518e-02, -1.74591187e-02, -1.02144917e-02, ...,
>        8.63332115e-03, -7.53870059e-04,  1.45421876e-02],
>      [-3.04296939e-03, -1.50832683e-02,  1.51605168e-02, ...,
>       -6.79229852e-03,  1.01285530e-02, -1.75108504e-03],
>      [-4.07854374e-03, -1.88519584e-03,  1.14850025e-03, ...,
>       -2.26586498e-02, -3.04668397e-03,  1.14008989e-02],
>      ...,
>      [ 1.17204599e-02,  2.86580436e-03, -1.76627021e-02, ...,
>        3.94910201e-03, -2.89543215e-02,  2.58394983e-03],
>      [ 1.01766353e-02, -2.09429841e-02, -1.05689308e-02, ...,
>       -3.20194196e-03, -3.15695629e-02,  3.79671482e-03],
>      [-4.92773578e-03, -4.51938109e-03, -2.68228631e-03, ...,
>        5.92946680e-03, -4.65792231e-03, -5.96702285e-03]]]],
>   dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_4/bias:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32, numpy= array([-0.00168076,  0.00166215, -0.00167152,
> ```
>
> -0.00130922, -0.00164626,
> 0.00166992, -0.00168149, -0.00057945, -0.00169018, -0.00143871,
> 0.00167122,  0.00168618,  0.00167541,  0.00169117, -0.00165321,
> 0.00167541, -0.00166706,  0.00165939,  0.00165955,  0.00162764,
> 0.00166588,  0.00168612,  0.00167851,  0.00167884,  0.0016743 ,
> 0.00171701,  0.00165294,  0.00167435,  0.00167905,  0.00165572,
> 0.00167356, -0.00166708, -0.00168088, -0.00166456, -0.00167135,
> -0.00167006,  0.00167656,  0.00170659,  0.00167328,  0.00166088,
> -0.0016864 , -0.00166293, -0.00176472, -0.00166444,  0.00167372,
> 0.00166756,  0.00168708,  0.00167746, -0.00167006,  0.00166973,
> -0.00167239,  0.00163416, -0.00165197, -0.00167195,  0.00166292,
> 0.00165982,  0.00167608, -0.00168473,  0.00166501,  0.00167176,
> 0.00171711,  0.00167139,  0.00167133, -0.00167868,  0.00160735,
> 0.00166808,  0.00167025, -0.00161975,  0.00167196, -0.00167264,
> -0.00166804,  0.00174853,  0.00169298,  0.00165326, -0.00166989,
> 0.00166873,  0.0016681 , -0.00164396, -0.00170325,  0.00167879,
> -0.00166963, -0.00166775, -0.00166631,  0.00168302,  0.0016176 ,
> -0.00166655,  0.00166208, -0.00171519,  0.00167442, -0.00166131,
> 0.00167713,  0.0016614 ,  0.00164063,  0.00160119, -0.00166949,
> -0.00167486,  0.0016609 , -0.00165791,  0.00167266, -0.00156529,
> 0.00164661, -0.00167219,  0.00167742,  0.00167498,  0.00166841,
> -0.00168209, -0.00166704,  0.00167016,  0.00168282, -0.00163766,
> -0.0016084 ,  0.00168005, -0.00166668, -0.00167182,  0.00141747,
> 0.00157016,  0.00168845,  0.00166997, -0.00167921,  0.00166262,
> 0.00167095,  0.00165517, -0.00167311, -0.00168072,  0.00167287,
> -0.00164948,  0.00166803,  0.00160261], dtype=float32)>]